# Fastest way to select column from 2D array in Python?

Tags: python, performance

I'm trying to improve performance of a function that counts the number of occurrences of a certain element in a column of a 2D array in Python. Times are from cProfile, which also tells me `count()` is only taking ~.08s per 357595 calls.

A for loop is fastest (.375s for 357595 calls):

```
def count_column(grid, j, element):
    count = 0
    for x in range(0, len(grid)):
        if grid[x][j] == element:
            count += 1
    return count
```

List comprehensions are slower by a negligible amount (.400s for 357595 calls):

```
def count_column(grid, j, element):
    return [x[j] for x in grid].count(element)
```

Zip is the slowest by a huge margin (.741s for 357595 calls):

```
def validate_column(grid, j, element):
    return zip(*grid)[j].count(element)
```

Are there any faster ways to do this, or would the best approach be to flatten the array with `chain.from_iterable`?

Comment: Have you considered using `numpy`?

Comment: In any other case, I totally would, but the machine I have to run the script on doesn't have it and I'm not allowed to install it.

Comment: Python 2.7.3, but is there a better way to do it in 3?

Comment: Probably not, it's just that in Py3, `zip` is lazy, while in 2, it's not. Which brings me to my next point: Have you tried using lazy results instead of strict—replace the list comprehension with a generator expression, replace `zip` with `itertools.izip`, replace the function with a generator—and using `itertools.count` instead of the `list.count` method?

Comment: You could use `xrange` instead of `range` in python 2.

Comment: Other alternatives: 1. Use `filter` (or `itertools.ifilter`), then `count` (or `itertools.count`) the result. 2. Use a `collections.Counter` to build up counts instead of building up a zipped list, then just `return c[element]`.

Comment: Maybe you can try this generator comprehension: `return sum(x[j] == element for x in grid)`.

Comment: @Akavall xrange did it, bringing the time down to .287s. Thanks!

Comment: @xjtian: how large is your array?  I want to compare my timings.

Comment: `timeit` is your friend.

Comment: @xjtian, could you install numpy in your home folder? If you install the Python package, rather than your operating system's `.msi` or `.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the timings I got for a bunch of different variations:

```
cc_explicit 5000 0.00290012359619
cc_explicit_xrange 5000 0.00145506858826
cc_filter 5000 0.00117516517639
cc_genexp 5000 0.00100994110107
cc_ifilter 5000 0.00170707702637
cc_izip 1 3.21103000641
cc_listcomp 5000 0.000788927078247
cc_zip 5000 12.1080589294
```

The code and test driver is at http://pastebin.com/WSAUqTyv

Since zip and izip were so slow, I took them out of the equation and ran a 500000x10 test with the rest:

```
cc_explicit 500000 0.105982065201
cc_explicit_xrange 500000 0.103507995605
cc_filter 500000 0.0856108665466
cc_genexp 500000 0.0679898262024
cc_ifilter 500000 0.144966125488
cc_listcomp 500000 0.0396680831909
```

So, the fastest solution was `listcomp`. But when I threw random data and larger rows at it, `genexp` and `explicit_xrange` both sometimes beat `listcomp`, and they're all pretty close in most of the tests, and `genexp` uses much less memory, so I'd go with that:

```
def cc_genexp(grid, j, element):
    return sum(x[j] == element for x in grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I can offer my two cents here, you should also look into *Numpy*, as has already been suggested. Or, if you don't want to deal with a non-standard library, you should check out `collections.Counter()`. Yes, it comes with a large up-front cost but if you find yourself doing counts for a lot of different values in the same dataset, you may find that the initial investment pays off.